# Custom JSON to XML conversion using JSON.Net

Tags: c#, xml, json, json.net, converters

I am using (Newtonsoft's) JSON.Net library with C#, and I want to customize a single part of its default XML conversion.

For example, if I wanted to change the XML conversion of arrays, than say I have the following JSON string:

```
{
    "object":
    {
        "a": 
        {
            [
                "d",
                "e",
                "f"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

If I convert it to XML using JSON.Net's default converter, I get:

```
<object>
    <a>d</a>
    <a>e</a>
    <a>f</a>
</object>
```

But, I want it to convert to:

```
<object>
    <a special:type="array">
        <element>d</element>
        <element>e</element>
        <element>f</element>
    </a>
</object>
```

Can I somehow take the existing method of conversion and change it a bit?

Both XML and JSON are tree-based structures, which should make their parsers modular. So I'm looking for a class that I can use to override its conversion function in the spirit of:

```
protected override XmlNode ToXmlNode(JsonNode jNode)
{
    if (jNode.Type == JsonType.Array)
    {
        XmlNode xNode = this.XDocument.CreateElement(jNode.Name)
        foreach (JsonNode jSub in jNode.Children)
        {
            var newJSub = jSub.Clone();
            newJSub.Name = "element";
            xNode.AppendChild(this.ToXmlNode(newJSub));
        }
        return xNode;
    }
    else
        return base.ToXmlNode(jNode);
}
```

(I'm using .Net v2.0)

Does anyone know anything that can help?

Comment: I cannot see any way to override what you need in the XmlNodeConverter class. You would likely need to make your own inheritor of JsonTextWriter and pass that to the XmlNodeConverter.

Answer (score 0):

Internally, Json.Net uses a special `JsonConverter` called `XmlNodeConverter` to do the conversion from JSON to XML or vice-versa.  This converter does not seem to be very extensible as it is, but you could create your own custom converter using the [`XmlNodeConverter` source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/XmlNodeConverter.cs) as a starting point, then plug that back into Json.Net.

```
XmlDocument doc = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<XmlDocument>(json, yourCustomXmlNodeConverter);
```